# Should we use Spring @Bean with static method?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-bean

Is this a good practice to use @Bean with static method?

```
public class Foo {
}
```

```
@Configuration
public FooFactory {

    @Bean
    public static Foo getFoo() {
        return new Foo();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally speaking, there's no need for `@Bean` methods to be static.

When a `@Bean` method is not static, creating the bean requires an instance of its class, `FooFactory` in your example, to be created first. The vast majority of the time this is fine, but it can sometimes cause a problem if the bean is of a type that is required very early in the application context's lifecycle. Two examples of such types are `BeanPostProcessor` and `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`. In these cases you should declare the `@Bean` method as static to allow the bean to be created without first creating an instance of your `@Configuration` class.

You can learn more about this at the end of [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factorybeans-annotations) in Spring Framework's reference documentation:

> You may declare `@Bean` methods as static, allowing for them to be called without creating their containing configuration class as an instance. This makes particular sense when defining post-processor beans (for example, of type `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` or `BeanPostProcessor`), since such beans get initialized early in the container lifecycle and should avoid triggering other parts of the configuration at that point.
>
> Calls to static `@Bean` methods never get intercepted by the container, not even within `@Configuration` classes (as described earlier in this section), due to technical limitations: CGLIB subclassing can override only non-static methods. As a consequence, a direct call to another `@Bean` method has standard Java semantics, resulting in an independent instance being returned straight from the factory method itself.